# Install specific PyTorch version (pytorch==1.0.1)

Tags: macos, pip, pytorch, conda

I'm trying to install specific PyTorch version under conda env:

Using pip:

```
pip3 install pytorch==1.0.1
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pytorch==1.0.1 (from versions: 0.1.2, 1.0.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pytorch==1.0.1
```

Using Conda:

```
conda install pytorch==1.0.1
    Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
    Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
    Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
    Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
    
    PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
    
      - pytorch==1.0.1
    
    Current channels:
    
      - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
      - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
      - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
      - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
    
    To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
    looking for, navigate to
    
        https://anaconda.org
    
    and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

I was able to find this version under https://anaconda.org/soumith/pytorch but is there a way to find it and install from console?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can download/install the version you like from the official [Pytorch's Conda package](https://anaconda.org/pytorch/pytorch/files?version=1.0.1). the link you specified is an old version and is not supported/updated for quit some time now!.
Install your desired version like this :

```
conda install pytorch==1.0.1 torchvision==0.2.2 -c pytorch
```

If you are looking for a pip version, you can view and access all versions from [here](https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html) as well.

and simply do :

```
pip install torch===1.0.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

You can always check the [previous versions](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/) here as well.

Answer (score -2):

You could download a previous version of pytorch by using any of these :
*For Linux/Windows Specific OS*

```
# CUDA 9.0
conda install pytorch==1.0.1 torchvision==0.2.2 cudatoolkit=9.0 -c pytorch

# CUDA 10.0
conda install pytorch==1.0.1 torchvision==0.2.2 cudatoolkit=10.0 -c pytorch

# CPU Only
conda install pytorch-cpu==1.0.1 torchvision-cpu==0.2.2 cpuonly -c pytorch
```

Visit this [website](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/)  to see how to install pytorch versions on your specific operating software. I hope this answer was helpful.